# C string one character shorter than defined length?

Tags: c++, cstring

Very new to c++ and I have the following code:

```
char input[3];

cout << "Enter input: ";
cin.getline(input,sizeof(input));
cout << input;
```

And entering something like `abc` will only output `ab`, cutting it one character short. The defined length is 3 characters so why is it only capturing 2 characters?

Comment: ***The defined length is 3 characters so why is it only capturing 2 characters?*** You need an extra character for the null terminator.

Comment: Thank you! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If you're new to C++, don't use weird quirks like C-style strings yet. Use `std::string`, which just works how you'd expect, then learn how it works when you're ready to face true madness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that c-strings are null terminated. To store 3 characters you need to allocate space for 4 because of the null terminator.

Also as the @MikeSeymour mentioned in the comments in c++ its best to avoid the issue completely and use std::string.

Answer (score 3):

You can thank your favorite deity that this fail-safe is in, most functions aren't that kind.

In C, strings are null-terminated, which means they take an extra character than the actual data to mark where the string actually ends.

Since you're using C++ anyway, you should avoid bare-bones char arrays. Some reasons:

- **buffer overflows**. You managed to hit this issue on your first try, take a hint!
- **Unicode awareness**. We're living in 2015. Still using 256 characters is unacceptable by any standard.
- **memory safety**. It's way harder to leak a proper `string` than a plain old array. `string`s have strong copy semantics that cover pretty much anything you can think of.
- **ease of use**. You have the entire STL algorithm list at your disposal! Use it rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Could you expand upon Unicode awareness? I'm not exactly familiar with what that means, and why having 256 characters is unacceptable.

Comment: I take it you're American. The world unfortunately is in majority non-American, and some of those crazy non-Americans have goofy ways of writing, and those goofy characters don't fit in your cozy little 256 characters. 미안해!